# How to add path for C compiler

Tags: kernel, compiling, gcc

My program file is using header files in `/usr/include/linux` and some other header files (such as `slabs.h`) in `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-26/include/linux`.

The gcc compiler fails to recognize the header files from the latter and throws fatal compilation error.

How to add the latter path for compilation.

I tried giving absolute path and using command like `gcc -I {additional path} myFile.c -o myFile`.

Comment: Have you tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH ? Something like: `export LF_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-26/include/linux `

Comment: What you tried (using `-I`) is the correct way to add **include** paths - if you need further help, show us the **actual** command and the **complete** error message (perhaps it isn't about the header files at all?)

Comment: @steeldriver The command is: gcc -I /usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-26/include/linux dwav-usb-mt.c -o dwav-usb-mt

Comment: The error is: fatal error: linux/slab.h : No such file or directory. compilation terminated. slab.h is present int he above provided path

Comment: @SorenA yes, I did what you suggested. It shows the same problem.

Comment: If the file is included in your source code as `<linux/slab.h>` then the path would be given as `gcc -I /usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-26/include/` - if you add `/linux` to the path then it's going to be looking for `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-26/include/linux/linux/slab.h`. As an aside, you shouldn't normally be including kernel headers in userspace code.